# What magic weapon makes damage rolls of 1, 2 or 3 count as 4?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, damage, content-identification

I know I have seen in one of the 4e books, a magic weapon with a property that if you make a damage roll of 1, 2 or 3, those rolls become a 4. I cannot remember what book I had seen it in or what it was called. Does anyone have any idea what book or the name of it it?

Answer (score 7):

In the end it turns out it was the paragon guild executioner paragon path feature *executioner's action*.

> when you spend an action point to make an attack, and you roll a 1, 2
>   or 3 on any damage die associated with that attack (including extra
>   damage from assassin's strike or critical hit dice), that die instead
>   deals 4 damage.

I had several books open at the time and somehow ended up thinking that this was a weapon property on a magic weapon.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You appear to have accidentally created more than one account. You will be unable to accept answers to your own question until you [merge your accounts using the instructions in the help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6):

The [Devastating Ki Focus](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1076) almost does this, 1 and 2 are counted as 3. It is from page 6 of Dragon Magazine #398 - the Heroes of Shadow section which didn't make it into the Heroes of Shadow supplement book.

There is also the artifact [Heartwood Spear](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=150), from Dungeon #187 that turns 1 and 2 into 3.

I could not find any weapons or implements that makes 1-3 into 4.